# Сбрасываются счётчики соц.сетей

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Поставили на страницу

```html
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook" data-counter=""></div>
```

Вчера отображало 5 в ВК, сегодня - просто кнопки отображаются.
С чем связано это?
Или каждый день сбрасывается что-то и это так задумано?

---

Вот здесь:
https://yandex.ru/blog/share/obnulilis-layki-na-knopke-vkontakte
Но что значит www.
Вот допустим у меня есть www.site.ru и его синонимы site.ru, сайт.рф
Мы же вставляли кнопки по адресу site.ru и туда же собственно и заходим и наблюдаем эту картину.

Comment: Добавить хотелось бы. Если страница отдаётся через "www" учёт отобразился. К чему это?

Comment: Значит, кнопки раньше указывали на www.site.ru. Вы можете явно указать адрес с www в атрибуте data-url.